# How to create partitioned deciles in tableau? (decile within certain groups)

Tags: formula, tableau-api, partition

So I need to create deciles for a variable, but not across the total column, i need partitioned deciles. Essentially, here's what my data looks like:

```
EmployeeID | Year | Position | Salary
```

I need to create deciles within Salary, but by year and position. So 10 groups for each position in a given year.

I am new to tableau and struggling to come up with the formulas to achieve this.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Create deciles by using PERCENTILE function in Tableau.
Example for 2nd Decile:

```
PERCENTILE([Measure Value],0.20)
```